# Newsletter box not working

Tags: magento-1.7, newsletter

My newsletter box doesn't work any more, it doesn't send emails to the backend. 
here's the block i'm using: `{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}`

How can i make it work again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block type should be newsletter/subscribe so the following should work

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="ANYNAME" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```